# Why would `node --inspect` not stop at a given Chrome DevTools breakpoint? (while `debugger;` works)

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, webpack, google-chrome-devtools

I am debugging a Webpack build by using `node --inspect` and Chrome DevTools.

I see that my output file contains a piece of code with the comment `/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */`.  If I put a break point right at the Webpack code that generates that comment, the debugger won't stop at that breakpoint when running the build in debug mode, but it stops when I place `debugger;`.  Why?

**EDIT:**

The (last version of the) code I am referring to can be seen in
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/NormalModule.js

Here I paste an extract. I expected the debugger to stop at any breakpoint I put inside this function (except inside places like the function passed to `.map` and `.forEach`).  (This is the only piece of code in Webpack that writes `/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */`):

```
    function doBlock(block) {
        console.log("1 What the F*** is going on with this debugger?");
        block.dependencies.forEach(doDep);
        block.blocks.forEach(doBlock);
        if(block.variables.length > 0) {
            var vars = [];
            block.variables.forEach(doVariable.bind(null, vars));
            var varNames = [];
            var varExpressions = [];
            var varStartCode = "";
            var varEndCode = "";

            function emitFunction() {
                console.log("2 Why the F*** is it that a breakpoint right here doesn't stop the debugger?");
                if(varNames.length === 0) return;

                varStartCode += "/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(" + varNames.join(", ") + ") {";
                // exports === this in the topLevelBlock, but exports do compress better...
                varEndCode = (topLevelBlock === block ? "}.call(exports, " : "}.call(this, ") +
                    varExpressions.map(function(e) {
                        return e.source();
                    }).join(", ") + "))" + varEndCode;

                varNames.length = 0;
                varExpressions.length = 0;
            }
            vars.forEach(function(v) {
                if(varNames.indexOf(v.name) >= 0) emitFunction();
                varNames.push(v.name);
                varExpressions.push(v.expression);
            });
            emitFunction();
            console.log("3 Are you not gonna stop here, debugger? Are you F****** kidding me?");
            var start = block.range ? block.range[0] : 0;
            var end = block.range ? block.range[1] : _source.size();
            if(varStartCode) source.insert(start + 0.5, varStartCode);
            if(varEndCode) source.insert(end + 0.5, "\n/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */" + varEndCode);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the actual lines of code that you are asking about (both before and after the line you want to break on).

Comment: Generally, assuming you are using source maps, it won't stop if that line is not present in the actual compiled code.